# solving $\sqrt{2 x^4-3 x^2+1}+\sqrt{2x^4-x^2}=4 x-3.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, sum-of-squares-method

I am trying to solve this equation
$$\sqrt{2 x^4-3 x^2+1}+\sqrt{2x^4-x^2}=4 x-3.$$
By using *Mathematica*, I know that, the equation has unique solution  $x=1$.
I tried to write the equation in the form
$$\sqrt{(x-1) (x+1) \left(2x^2-1\right)} + \sqrt{x^2\left(2x^2-1\right)} =4 x-3.$$
From here, I can not solve it. How can I solve it?

Comment: Move one term with radical sign to the right, square both sides, you end up with only one term with radical sign. Repeat to remove the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let $a=2x^4-3x^2+1,b=2x^4-x^2$ where $ a,b\ge 0$ now $\sqrt{a+b}=2x^2-1$ so $$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-4x+3=0$$ $$\to \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{a+b}-4x+3=0$$  $$\to \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a+b}+2{(x-1)}^2=0$$ because $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\ge \sqrt{a+b}$ $$\to x=1 \space  \text{and} \space \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a+b}$$ $$\to x=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the domain of the equation is $x\ge1$ and
$$\sqrt{2x^4-x^2} - (2x^2-1)= \sqrt{2x^2-1} \left( x-\sqrt{2x^2-1}\right)
= -\frac{\sqrt{2x^2-1} (x^2-1)}{x+\sqrt{2x^2-1} }
$$

Then, factorize the equation as follows

\begin{align}
&\sqrt{2 x^4-3 x^2+1}+\sqrt{2x^4-x^2}-(4 x-3)\\
=& \sqrt{(x^2-1) (2x^2-1)} +\left( \sqrt{x^2(2x^2-1)} - (2x^2-1)\right)+2(x^2-1)^2\\
 =& \sqrt{(x^2-1) (2x^2-1)} -\frac{\sqrt{2x^2-1} (x^2-1)}{x+\sqrt{2x^2-1} } +2(x^2-1)^2 \\
 =& \sqrt{(x^2-1) (2x^2-1)} \> \frac{x+\sqrt{2x^2-1}-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x+\sqrt{2x^2-1} } +2(x^2-1)^2 \\
 =& \sqrt{(x^2-1) (2x^2-1)} \> \frac{x+\sqrt{2x^2-1}-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x+\sqrt{2x^2-1} } +2(x^2-1)^2\\
=& \sqrt{x^2-1}\cdot f(x)
\end{align}
where
$$f(x) = \sqrt{2x^2-1} \> \frac{x+\sqrt{2x^2-1}-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x+\sqrt{2x^2-1} } +2\sqrt{x^2-1}>0
$$

Thus, $x=1$ is the sole solution.